# Apigility and index.phtml template

Tags: zend-framework2, php, laminas-api-tools

I am trying to create a index.phtml page to my RESTful Apigility API. Steps i have taken is 
1) Create a DB connected API any given it route "account"
2) Access the account API on /account with postman and got HAL and JSON to response to work
3) Create a new "Selector" under content negotiation with 3 view models. "ZF\ContentNegotiation\ViewModel", "ZF\Hal\View\HalJsonModel" and "Zend\View\Model\ViewModel"
4) Selected the newly created selector in the accounts API 
5) Created a index.phtml under Account/view/index.phtml with code "

## Test

"
6) Added

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'account' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```

to module.config.php

7) Using postman and accessed /account with 
    Accept    application/json   // works
    Accept    text/html          // don't work

Would be great if someone could lend a hand to get a index.phtml template to work with a restful DB connect API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ViewModel` you should choose [RPC API](https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/what-is-an-api#rpc). You can create `RPC API` with following this documentation

https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/getting-started#create-an-rpc-service

Comment: Thanks Dolly.
What i am trying to achieve is to create a ViewModel that i can use for a SPA (Singel Page Application) with my REST based API, similar to what the admin ui is based upon.